# Laravel - Implement eloquent relations in repository

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, repository-pattern

I have 3 models for managing user permissions.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission');
    }
}

class Permission extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    }

    public function roleHavePermission(Role $role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->find($role->id)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function userHavePermission(User $user = null)
    {
        $roles = [];

        if (is_null($user)) {
            $roles[] = Role::where('slug', 'guest')->first();
        } else {
            foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
                $roles[] = $role;
            }
        }

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->roleHavePermission($role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now because my application is grown, I'm moving to repositories. For example this is my `PermissionRepository`:

```
class PermissionRepository implements PermissionRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $roleRepository;

    /**
     * PermissionRepository constructor.
     * @param RoleRepositoryInterface $roleRepository
     */
    public function __construct(RoleRepositoryInterface $roleRepository)
    {
        $this->roleRepository = $roleRepository;
    }

    public function action($routeName)
    {
        return Permission::where('action', $routeName)->first();
    }
}
```

How can I implement `roleHavePermission` and `userHavePermission` in this repository? I tried implementing `roles` method with this syntax:

```
public function roles()
{
    return Permission::roles();
}
```

But it wont work since Permission's roles method can not called statically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact in my opinion you shouldn't implement it in repository. When you call

```
$permission = $permissionRepository->action('abc.name');
```

you are getting permission object, so there is no point to implement it in repository. All you need is running:

```
$roles = $permission->roles;
```

In theory you could add for example into PermissionRepository method like this:

```
public function getRoles(Permission $permission) 
{
  return $permission->roles;
}
```

so you could now run

```
$roles = $permissionRepository->getRoles($permission);
```

to get roles of given permission but I don't see any point to do it like this.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!